# Understanding asio::async_read behavior

Tags: boost, asio

I've inherited code that extensively uses `asio::async_*` methods to integrate with my main project. In my main project I'm using `io_context::post()` to have some control over the scheduling and dispatching of the connections.

The application is a client running on an infinite loop with tens of thousands of connections to different hosts.

I'd like to know more about the `asio::async_*` behavior. I do know that `io_context::post()` dispatches work items to the system and schedules the callbacks on the thread(s) running `io_context::run()`.

My first thought is to simply pass the `io_context` around and `.post()` on that instance, but that doesn't look like a good design choice to me.

AFAIK, I can't cleanly implement back pressure with the `asio::async_*` methods (pardon my blatant ignorance if I'm mistaken, `asio`'s documentation isn't the most abundant), which is why I'm trying to have the whole application `.post()` to `io_context` so I can control and not DoS my machine.

edit: updated the title

Answer (score 1):

You can find a concise but sufficient to provide an understanding description of *sync* and *async* operations on an example of `connect` and `async_connect` functions here: [Basic Boost.Asio Anatomy](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/basics.html)